# Pixels To Xamarin.Forms Font Size

Tags: xamarin.forms, pixel

i am using Xamarin forms and i have a project that requires the font size to be 32 pixels. I kept searching on google however i could not find an answer on how to convert this pixels in Xamarin device-independent units. I would greatly appreciate some help.

Thank you.

Comment: I would push back on this - some devices have pixel densities above 500 PPI, meaning a 32 pixel font would be unreadable

Comment: Ah, thats why when i tried to convert px to dp in xxxhdpi the font was almost unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **[custom renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry)** to invoke native method to set 32 pixels.Based on **Button** control, you can create a custom `Button` in Xamaarin forms as follows:

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
}
```

Then Andoird solution create the custom rendere class as follows:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.MyButton), typeof(CustomButtonRenderer))]
namespace AppShellTest.Droid
{
    [Obsolete]
    public class CustomButtonRenderer: ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                // do whatever you want to the UITextField here!
                Control.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Px, 32);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

About other controls, also can create their custom renderers to do.

=================================Update===============================

The method that can convert `dp` to `px` or `px` to `dp`, you can check that whether it works for you.

```
public int dip2px(Context context, float dpValue)
{
    float scale = context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
    return (int)(dpValue * scale + 0.5f);
}


public int px2dip(Context context, float pxValue)
{
    float scale = context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
    return (int)(pxValue / scale + 0.5f);
}
```

Then renderer code will be:

```
public class CustomButtonRenderer: ButtonRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            // do whatever you want to the UITextField here!
            Control.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Px, dip2px(32));
        }
    }

    public int dip2px(float dpValue)
    {
        float scale = MainActivity.instance.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
        return (int)(dpValue * scale + 0.5f);
    }
}
```

The **MainActivity.instance** declared in **MainActivity** that means the instance of MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    public static MainActivity instance { set; get; }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        instance = this;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
...
```

Comment: Thanks, when i use this code with 32 pixels in my >500ppi device the font is too small. I think they have taken the size form their website that uses pixels for font size, is there a way we can match the dp with the website pixels ?

Comment: I will update the answer, you can have a check whether the convert method works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin uses DIU (device-independent units) about everywhere.
Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter05

I had a similiar issue and found out via trial and error that *Xamarin.Essentials.DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density* returns the amount of pixels per DIU on the device (tested on iPod Touch, Nokia 8 and Firetablet).

So this should be correct:

```
myLabel.FontSize = 32 / Xamarin.Essentials.DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density;
```

But as Jason has stated, you might want to check your requirements, because the more pixels are on the device, smaller the font gets. Thats why people use DIU in the first place :-)
It is probably better to have a look at how big the font is on the customers homepage. Maybe measure it there in inches, centimeters or whatever fits you and then do the math to convert that to DIUs (see link above, 64 DIU = 1 centimeter).